# Given $x^2+y^2>0$ where $x,y \in R$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Find the maximum and minimum value of the following expression E

$$E=\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2}$$

Comment: Well, your answer isn't correct.  $(x,y)=(-1,-1)$ still satisfies the inequality.

Comment: ok, can x be zero? In that case (x,y)=$\left(0,1\right)$ also satisifies

Comment: Of course $x$ can be $0$.

Comment: but how to write range for x and y?

Comment: Well, try approaching it from the other direction.  Can you solve $x^2+y^2≤0$ for $x,y\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: I don't understand the edit.  Are you now asking a completely different question?

Comment: No I missed this part of the question, actually earlier I broke this question into two sub parts , but this is now the complete question.

Comment: my confusion is that can we divide both numerator and denominator by $x^2$,

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be restated as:

There exists $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+y^2>0$, i.e. $x\neq 0$ or $y\neq 0$ and $E=\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}+x y+4 y^{2}}$, find the maximum and minimum of $E$.

Which is equivalent with:

There exists $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\neq 0$ or $y\neq 0$ and $(E-1)x^2+Exy+(4E-1)y^2=0$, find the maximum and minimum of $E$.

Suppose $y\neq 0$ WLOG and set $t=\dfrac{x}{y}$, we have $(E-1)t^2+Et+(4E-1)=0$ has a solution, which means the discriminant $\Delta= E^2-4(E-1)(4E-1)=-15E^2+20E-4\geqslant 0$ therefore $\dfrac{2-2\sqrt{2/5}}{3}\leqslant E \leqslant \dfrac{2+2\sqrt{2/5}}{3}$.

Comment: +1 - I was just about to post a very similar answer when your answer came in.

Comment: but in the question it is given $x^2+y^2>0$, how can you divide by y as we don't know  if y is equal to zero or not

Comment: can you give answer to my comment?

Comment: Okay, since $x^2+y^2>0$, so at least one of $x,y$ is nonzero. So we can first assume $y\neq 0$. Next assume $x\neq 0$, which gives the same answer.

Comment: so here you mean to say luckily we are getting the answer by assuming x=0 or y=0, can there be cases , when we get different answers, I am just asking to save time.

Comment: How to figure out such combination:- $(E-1)x^2+Exy+(4E-1)y^2=0$?

Answer (score 1):

With $$y=ux$$ we have $$\dfrac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}+x y+4 y^{2}}= \frac {1+u^2}{1+u+4u^2} =f(u)$$

$$f'(u)=0 \implies u=3\pm \sqrt {10}$$

The maximum value is $$f(3-\sqrt {10})=1.0883037..$$ and the minimum value is $$f(3+\sqrt {10})=0.245029645...$$

Comment: but how do you know that f''(u) is negative for one value of u and positive for another value, did you calculate f''(u), f'(u) is a very long expression

Comment: In real time it is not feasible to calculate f''(u)

Comment: @user3290550  $f'(u)=\frac {u^2-6u-1}{ (4u^2+u+1)^2}$ is easy to check.

Comment: but to know that which value of u is giving maximum value and minimum value, we need to calculate double derivative , which is difficult to calculate

Comment: @user3290550  first derivative test will do.

Comment: how first derivative will do, by first derivative you will be able to only find values of u, but to check which value of u is giving minimum or maximum, you need to calculate the double derivative.

Comment: @ Mohammad Riazi-Kermani , can you please tell me how first derivative will do, I am just a learner

Comment: At $u=3$  we have $ f'(3) = <0$ so f(u) is decreasing and  out side $(3-\sqrt {10}, 3+\sqrt {10}) $, $f'(u) >0$ so $f(u)$ is decreasing.  So the smaller critical point is a maximizer, while the larger one is a minimizer.

Answer (score 1):

A sketch of a possible solution:

you want to find the extrema of $E(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2}$ on $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}.$

Switching to polar coordinates gives $E(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta+\sin \theta \cos \theta+4\sin^2\theta}$ so $E$ is independent of $r$ and bounded on all of $\mathbb R^2.$ So if it has extrema, they will occur along radial lines.

Set $f(\theta)=\cos^2\theta+\sin \theta \cos \theta+4\sin^2\theta$ and simplify:

$f(\theta)=\cos^2\theta+\sin \theta \cos \theta+4\sin^2\theta=1+\frac{1}{2}\sin2\theta+\frac{3}{2}(1-\cos2\theta)=$

$\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin2\theta-3\cos2\theta\right).$

This expression is never zero, (but we already proved this when we noted that $E$ is bounded). Now, apply the usual calculus I analysis of $f$: on $[0,2\pi],\ f$ has exactly two maxima and two minima, and relate the result to $E$ to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing $E$ is the same as to optimize
$$
F=\frac{1}{E}=\frac{x^2+xy+4y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1+\frac{xy+3y^2}{x^2+y^2}.
$$
Introduce the polar coordinates $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$. Then
\begin{align}
F&=1+\sin\phi\cos\phi+3\sin^2\phi=1+\frac{1}{2}(\sin2\phi+3(1-\cos2\phi))=\\
&=\frac52+\frac12(\sin2\phi-3\cos2\phi)=\frac52+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}\sin(2\phi+\delta)
\end{align}
where in the last equality [the standard rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine) is done.

Now it is clear that $F$ changes between $\frac{5\pm\sqrt{10}}{2}$. For the original $E$ it corresponds to
$$
\frac{2}{5\pm\sqrt{10}}=\frac{2(5\mp\sqrt{10})}{15}.
$$